# Whats the best way of storing a stream of data of unknown range and distribution in a hash table which provides O(1) access?

Tags: java

Lets say we had a *stream of data* comming into us (of unknown range and distribution) and we wanted to **store the last X** number of values in a hash table which provides **O(1)** access, how would we do this?

For simplicity lets say the data is a *stream of numbers* of *unknown range and distribution*.
In order to **map** these numbers to an *element of an array* we would need a **hash function** that takes account of the *data range and distribution*.

I guess we'd either estimate this range upfront or maintain some statistics on the data coming in and adjust the hash function accordingly.

Also we'd need a way of rejigging the array one the X threshold is met.

Any thoughts or ideas for doing this as fast as possible?

Comment: Why don't you use a ring buffer?

Comment: Sure that would sort out the "array rejigging" as per above, but what about the hash function, anny ideas?

Comment: Why not use a LinkedHashMap which evicts the oldest entry when it is too old.  http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/unique-hashcodes-is-not-enough-to-avoid.html

Comment: A good hash function can cope with non uniform input distributions. There is no need to adjust to the inputs.

Comment: Why even use a Map at all?  I mean, what will the key be and what will the value be?  And how will you get a key later so that you can quickly get the value in O(1)?  Unless you can explain those more, a map makes little sense.  Why not just an array of whatever your type is and a circular counter?

Comment: Dynamic Perfect Hashing seems to be pretty close: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_perfect_hashing

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Perfect Hashing seems to be pretty close, combine this with an array growing strategy and your good to go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_perfect_hashing